# Executing vs Compiling a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I have some problems with `dbms_output`. I wrote this code and `dbms output` in SQL Developer doesn't work.

```
create or replace procedure imprimirNotEmpleat(no_nom varchar2)
as
  nom varchar2(30);
  cursor buscarnom is select nom_emp 
                      from empleats 
                      where nom_emp!=no_nom;
begin
  open buscarnom;
  fetch buscarnom into nom;
  while buscarnom%found loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Empleat: '||nom);
    fetch buscarnom INTO nom;
  end loop;
  close buscarnom;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting way of thinking there. You didn't get the expected result, so your conclusion is "`dbms_output` in SQL Developer doesn't work". Shouldn't your conclusion be "I must be doing something wrong" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **created** the procedure, but never **executed** it. It just *waits* in the database.

But, before executing the procedure, run

```
set serveroutput on
```

in SQL Developer to *enable* output, and then

```
begin
  imprimirNotEmpleat('ABC');   --> or whichever value it is
end;
/
```

Note that you won't see anything if cursor doesn't return any rows.